# Button hide and show reset

Tags: html

Hello I have a question I want to reset button if the fields are empty, the reset is not displayed if a value is entered, the reset is displayed
 Reset

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have your codes with you?

Comment: It is for 1 html where several reset buttons are created that have the same function

Answer (score 0):

for jquery ill recomand this

```
$( "input" ).change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val == ""){
     $("#yourresetbutton").hide();
  }else{
     $("#yourresetbutton").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: You can also do that with type of value or name instead of id or class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by this but I take it you want a button to appear only if a textbox if left blank. If so you this is some code you can use:

```
<input id='textbox' type='text'></input>
<button id='resetButton'></button>

setInterval(checkText, 10)
function checkText() {
    if(document.getElementById('textbox').value == '') {
        document.getElementById('resetButton').visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else() {
        document.getElementById('resetButton').visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```